# Secure communication End-to-end with android and Server

Tags: encryption, tls, vpn, android

I´m building a enterprise application and I need to create a secure communication between android and a server. What is the most secure way to do End-to-End communication? Should I use HTTPS or VPN? There are better options?

Comment: HTTPS + certificate pinning seems like an obvious route.

Comment: @domen you should post that as an answer, because it is the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS + certificate pinning seems like an obvious route.

Comment: Thats the way I will do. Just come here to know if there are more secure options to think about

Comment: What threats do you have in mind then?

Comment: I want to block anykind of threat. I want to create a complete secure app. Packet sniffing, packet change , MITM etc. . .

Comment: So just MITM basically. Obviously you'd also need to secure the app itself, client and server side. Can unauthorized/spoofed clients be a problem? But we're getting out of scope of "end-to-end communication".

Comment: Im creating a bank aplication. I have all the possible concerns! :)